# JVM code cache exceeds ReservedCodeCacheSize

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I have a java app running in a docker with flags on OpenJDK8:

```
-XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0 -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary
```

and I've noticed that Code Cache memory allocation reported by Native Memory Tracking tool exceeds `240MB` (default `ReservedCodeCacheSize` value):

```
jcmd 1 VM.native_memory summary | grep -i code
-                      Code (reserved=260013KB, committed=60465KB)
```

which is `~ 254MB` reserved memory. Here's printed flag and java version:

```
java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -i reserved
    uintx ReservedCodeCacheSize                     = 251658240                           {pd product}
openjdk version "1.8.0_262"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_262-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.262-b10, mixed mode)
```

My question is if this is expected behavior? If yes, then is it possible to calculate actual limit for the max code cache size?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Code` in the Native Memory Tracking report accounts not just Code Cache, but also a few other things. The report includes:

1. Fixed size spaces reserved with `mmap`:

   - Code Cache - 240 MB;
   - the map of the Code Cache segments - 1/64 of the Code Cache size = 3.75 MB.
2. Auxiliary VM structures `malloc`'ed in the native heap:

   - code strings, [OopMaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029764/what-does-oop-maps-means-in-hotspot-vm-exactly/26049445#26049445), exception handler caches, adapter handler tables, and other structures for maintaining the generated code.

     These structures are allocated dynamically; there is no a dedicated limit for them, but usually they make up only a small portion of the total generated code (see `malloc=` line in the `Code` section of the NMT report).

Note that `reserved` memory does not actually consume resources other than the address space. For analyzing the real memory usage, `committed` is more relevant.